# Car parking reservation availability query with date and time

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I am implementing a car parking reservation system in which a user reserves a parking space.

**reservation table**

```
columns
--------------
parkingSpaceId
VehicleId
UserId
startDate
startTime
EndDate
EndTime
```

**space table**

```
columns
--------
avialableSpaces
noOfBookings
```

User can check for available parking space with parameters `startDate`, `startTime`, `EndDate`, `EndTime`.

`if avialableSpaces==noOfBookings` then parking space is not available.

What is the logic to find out if a parking space is available between the startDate, StartTime and EndDate, EndTime?

Comment: Note that it should be "availableSpaces", not "avialableSpaces"

Answer (score 0):

You get the number of available parking lots at a certain time by asking for parkingSpaceIds for which not exist a booking time wherein your given time starts or ends.

BTW: Why do you split date and time in your table? The only reason for this that I can think of is the possibility to have one without the other, e.g. a day with no time specified (and no default time related). If this is the case you would have to consider this in above select. If not, you should change your table design.

EDIT: As your reservations table has a parkingSpaceId, I assume there is also a parking space table with a record per parking space. Here is a possible statement. It depends on the dbms how the statement would look exactly. I use Oracle's AddTime function here to combine date and time for easier comparision. It's always kind of akward to have to work with separate date and time fields  and if one of them is nullable - which would be the only sensible reason for the splitting - it's even more complicated. You will have to adjust the statement accordingly.

```
select parkingspaceid
from parkingspaces s
where not exists
(
  select *
  from reservations r
  where r.parkingspaceid = s.id
  and 
  (
    ( 
      addtime(:startdate,:starttime) >= addtime(r.startdate,r.starttime)
      and 
      addtime(:startdate,:starttime) < addtime(r.enddate,r.endtime)
    )
    or
    ( 
      addtime(:enddate,:endtime) >= addtime(r.startdate,r.starttime)
      and 
      addtime(:enddate,:endtime) < addtime(r.enddate,r.endtime)
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: yes my requirement is to split date and time.but i did not get that how i compare that parking space is available between stratDate startTime,EndDate and EndTime.as a parking space has no of available spaces and users can reserve them on hourly basis too.

Comment: Well, maybe I misunderstand. Let's see ... If I want to know if parkingSpaceId 123 is available on Friday from 10:00 to 11:00, I look for reservations covering that time. If I find a reservation from 9:00 to 10:30 then the place is not available, because the place is (partly) reserved at the desired time. I see this, because my start time 10:00 is in the range 9:00 to 10:30. So the method is to look wether EXISTS or not exists a range wherin either my start or end datetime lies for each parkingSpaceId.

Comment: reservation is on hourly basis.can you please write the sql query for my understanding.

Comment: I've added an SQL outline. I didn't use your space table, because it doesn't make much sense to me. I assume there to be another table with one record per parkingspaceid which I used.

Comment: shuold i convert date and hour to timespan?

Comment: I don't know any dbms supportimng time spans. You would usually model this by using a start time plus an end time or a duration. I would use a startdatetime and an enddatetime here. As to the enddatetime you will have to consider if you want it to be 11:00 or rather 10:59.999 .

Comment: I explained that AddTime is a function available in Oracle dbms. I use it to combine date and time to get a point in time with which I can work much easier than with the separate values. There should be similar functions in about every dbms.

Comment: Thank you.i am using ravendb.do you know how to combine date and time in this db

Comment: I don't know ravendb. On a quick glimpse it seems datetimes are stored as strings, so you might just concatenate them. I don't know if you use a plus sign for it or something else. Something along the lines of '2014-04-23' + 'T' + '13:59:59.9999999".

Answer (score -1):

```
select parkingspaceid
from parkingspaces s
where not exists
(
  select *
  from reservations r
  where r.parkingspaceid = s.id
  and 
  (
    ( 
      addtime(:startdate,:starttime) >= addtime(r.startdate,r.starttime)
      and 
      addtime(:startdate,:starttime) < addtime(r.enddate,r.endtime)
    )
    or
    ( 
      addtime(:enddate,:endtime) >= addtime(r.startdate,r.starttime)
      and 
      addtime(:enddate,:endtime) < addtime(r.enddate,r.endtime)
    )
  )
);
```